# Spring Security 3 check if user is authenticated

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-security

I'm working on an old Spring 3.0.7 project. I have to add a `jsp` accessible to anyone. I have to check if anyone who land on this page is an authenticated one or is an anonymous one, so I decide to use this

```
<security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
...
</security:authorize>
<security:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
....
</security:authorize>
```

to show proper contents to users. When I land on that `jsp` as a logged user everithing is fine. When I land on that without login `isAuthenticated()` does not return `false` but throws an Exception:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.jasper.JasperException: javax.servlet.ServletException: javax.servlet.jsp.JspException: org.springframework.beans.NotReadablePropertyException: Invalid property 'principal.username' of bean class [org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken]: Bean property 'principal.username' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
```

I'm pretty new to Spring, surely I miss something. But what?

**update**

This is my `jsp` relevant code:

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false" contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="security" uri="http://www.springframework.org/security/tags" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
<c:set var="contextPath" value="${pageContext.request.contextPath}"/>

<content tag="top">
    <security:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">
        <!-- authenticated users content -->
    </security:authorize> 
    <security:authorize access="isAnonymous()">
        <li><a href="${contextPath}/"><i class="login"></i> Login</a></li>
    </security:authorize>       
</content>
...
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5321883/beans-notreadablepropertyexception-in-spring-security

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3487162/why-does-calling-the-security-authentication-property-principal-displayname-in

Comment: @underdog hello I saw both the two question but I couldn't find them usefull, maybe I'm too new to Spring. May you add some info? Thank you.

Comment: Are you sure the problem is with isAuthenticated() ? For me its seems that you are trying to access principal property but for not logged in user principal object doesnt exist.

Comment: @jgr no I'm not so sure. Looking at http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/3.0.7.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/access/expression/SecurityExpressionRoot.html I expect that `isAuthenticated()` return me `false`, not an exception. Do I misunderstand how to use that function?

Comment: It should return false not exception, but i mean maybe u have some code above isAuthenticated() which cause exception, can u show full jsp code?

Comment: @jgr I update my question to add jsp's code I can show.

Comment: I dont see any errors in your code. But i can get exactly same error as you when i try this code in my jsp for not authenticated users:<sec:authentication property="principal.username" />

Answer (score 0):

have to add a jsp accessible to anyone??

Then dont include that jsp into this below security.xml file.

Inside the configuration element, you can restrict access to particular URLs with one or more elements. Each element specifies a URL pattern and a set of access attributes required to access the URLs. Remember that you must always include a wildcard at the end of a URL pattern. Failing to do so will make the URL pattern unable to match a URL that has request parameters.

```
 <security:http auto-config="true" >  
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/index*" access="ROLE_USER" />
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/Transit*" access="ROLE_USER" />
 <security:form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/index.htm"  
  authentication-failure-url="/loginerror.htm" />  
 <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" />
 </security:http>
```

When ever we are going to describe a url without any security, Then we should remove the particular url from the above lines of code under security configured xml file. for example if we dont need any security for index page then the above coding should look like this.

```
     <security:http auto-config="true" >  
     <security:intercept-url pattern="/Transit*" access="ROLE_USER" />
     <security:form-login login-page="/login.htm" default-target-url="/index.htm"  
      authentication-failure-url="/loginerror.htm" />  
     <security:logout logout-success-url="/logout.htm" />
     </security:http>
```